# VirtualBox: killed by Windows Update

Tags: windows-8, virtualbox, windows-update

My VirtualBox environment on Windows 8 has suddenly died since I rebooted after a Windows Update overnight. Existing virtual machines that were working perfectly yesterday won't boot, either through Vagrant or the VirtualBox GUI. Even a new machine created from scratch won't boot. The error is the same in all cases:

[image: VirtualBox error]

I've uninstalled the Windows Update, rebooted, uninstalled VirtualBox, rebooted, rolled back to earlier versions, and nothing seems to work. Can anybody suggest anything else I might try, short of completely reinstalling Windows?

Comment: Which version VirtualBox ?

Comment: 4.3.26. I also tried 4.3.22. Same thing.

Comment: Which update did you uninstall?

Comment: I thought I uninstalled all of the updates with today's date but when I went back into Windows Update they had reappeared. I don't know if that's because in my haste I failed to delete them, or if I forgot to turn off automatic updates and they were reapplied. I've since discovered that one particular update is the culprit.

Comment: The update causing the issue is KB3045999. See [https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=67355](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=67355) for details.

Comment: Good thing my WSUS server in the office hadn't released KB3045999 yet to my users. Managed to catch it just before the auto-approve went into effect. Thank you for the heads up !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue . I updated windows and VirtualBox-4.3.18-96516 stopped working with exactly the same message.

I uninstalled allt he windows update from overnight and reinsstalled virtual box VirtualBox-4.3.18-96516-Win.exe and now i am back in action..

Comment: Thanks. I did the same and it worked. Someone over at [virtualbox.org](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=67355) very kindly identified the specific update that causes the problem.

Comment: awesome!!. as long as we know what is causing it.